# Get Wordpress Featured image form external RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, rss-reader, rss2

I used the following code in my FUNCTIONS file:

```
add_action('rss2_item', 'add_my_rss_node');

function add_my_rss_node() {
    global $post;
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)):
        $thumbnail = get_attachment_link(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        echo("<image>{$thumbnail}</image>");
    endif;
}
```

Now I try to call that image and display it from site A to my site B with a custom RSS tempalte. This is the code of the template.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/feed.php');
$rss = fetch_feed('https://notrealurl.net/categoryname-feed/');
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(30);
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);
?>
<ul>
<?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
else
// Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>

<li>
<a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>">
<?php echo $item->get_title(); ?> 
<?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y @ g:i a'); ?>


</a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I see the image url in my rss feed now ( thanks to that functions script) and it is in a  tag.

Looks like this:  https://www.mywebsite./url-of-the-image/

They dont have a .jpg or .png extension at the end of the url. Not sure if that is how it needs to be. When I open that link I can see the image, and it works.

Can somebody please help me to figure this out ? I'm working on this thing for 2 days and can't figure it out. My PHP isn't great so that is most likely the reason why I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your function to get the attachment `src` instead of the `link`, and echo that `src` into a `<url>` tag inside the `<image>` RSS element (see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/rss_tag_image.asp)). 
Try this:

```
function add_my_rss_node() {
    global $post;
    if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)):
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        echo("<image><url>{$thumbnail}</url></image>");
    endif;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already got the URL that I need displayed in my RSS feed. The thing that I can't figure out is how to get it displayed below my <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y @ g:i a'); ?> tag.

So I can figure out what to to when I get the

<img src="WHAT-TO-DO-TO-GET-THE-LINK-IN-HERE">

So just to read the right url from that <image> tag.

Comment: try adding `var_dump($item);` to you php template to see what is in that object maybe...

Comment: also, did you try `get_thumbnail();` from SimplePie enclosure? see: http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_enclosure/get_thumbnail

Comment: Yes I tried that already. As I see it now it is a custom field in the rss feed and so it needs to be loaded some other way that I can't figure out. Any other tips ?